# How to save the data using rest API in the table

Tags: magento2

I have create request data need to save the data in the custom table using rest API endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a rest API endpoint. Your route has to call a service with a method. Then, make a preference for your API Class to your Model. Then in your Model save your data

```
    <route url="/V1/products" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

To illustrate a bit, `/V1/products` would be your route URL. With this route, we call the service `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` pointing on the `save()` method.
In the `di.xml` file you make your preference:

```
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository" />
```

And from your Model , you do what you need.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not getting the response data in the file. how to get response data